# serialVersionUID used by multiple entity classes in java with the same value

Tags: java

I found that many of the `serialVersionUID` of the entity classes in my project use the same value.

Now,there is no problem with my project, CURD is OK, but I think it is abnormal to use same value.

Is there a problem?[image]

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. There is lengthy discussion about that field at below link, but in short there is nothing to worry about with having same value for multiple classes like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There won't be any problem, as the serial number **works per class**.

The compiler uses the `serialVersionUID` to compare the versions of the class to guarantee that the **same version of that class was used for serializing it when you try to deserialize it**.

The `serialVersionUID` **facilitates the versioning of serialized data**. If you update some of those classes, you'll be able to change their serial version in order to avoid any deserialization with an older version of the class: As the UIDs won't match, the deserialization won't be successful. This guarantees data consistency through different versions of the serialized elements.

---

### [No problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU)

In resume: **There's no issue if more than a class hold the same `SerialVersionUID`** (*f.e:* **`1L`**), because as said, it works per class (*there's no "duplicate version UID classes" mechanism involved here*). It's just as correct as two elements that were updated independently and now both hold, as a coincidence, **`696969L`** as their serial id: *it's just each one's version number*.

Declaring a permanent value, for example, **`1L`**, is like telling the compiler: *trust me, this class didn't change, just deserialize it*.

**`1L`** is also the default serial version UID given to classes that implement the `Serializable` interface, meaning "*this is the first version*"; It will also become the last version for those classes that won't change.

---

Just to finish, the `serialVersionUID` of a class that does not implement `Serializable` is **`0L`**.

> **[Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html)**
>
> *If the class has defined `serialVersionUID` it is retrieved from the
> class.*
>
> *If the `serialVersionUID` is not defined by the class, it is
> computed from the definition of the class in the virtual machine.*
>
> *If the specified class is not serializable or externalizable, null is
> returned. The lookupAny method behaves like the lookup method, except
> that it returns the descriptor for any class, regardless of whether it
> implements Serializable. The `serialVersionUID` of a class that does not
> implement Serializable is* `0L`.

Comment: Hi,this is helpful.